# Delete Part of String in One Column if Part of String Exists in Another Column

Tags: r

I have a column that is supposed to be just the street address. I have another column that contains the city, state, and zip. Sometimes the street address column also contains the city, state, and zip. If that is the case, I want to delete the city, state, and zip from the street address column.

Sample of data frame:

[image]

I would like the code to check each row, and if the string in the CityStateZip column exists within the string in the StreetAdd column, then delete that part of the string in the StreetAdd column.

What I want to see:

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
data$StreetAdd <- gsub(data$CityStateZip, '', data$StreetAdd)
```

This is the warning I get:

> Warning message: In gsub(data$CityStateZip, "", data$StreetAdd) :
>   argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be
>   used

And it doesn't seem like anything in my data frame has changed

Comment: Sorry about the image links. I couldn't figure out how to just put the images directly in the post

Comment: Instead of images it is advised to use `dput` to share data so that people can copy-paste it directly into their console. Read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: This isn't working either:

Comment: I tried: str_replace(data$StreetAdd, datat$CityStateZip, "")

Answer (score 0):

Its not pretty, but it works:

```
library(dplyr)

street <- c("1234 Main St","5678 Park Pl Detroit MI 55555")
citystate <- c("Buffalo NY 14210", "Detroit MI 55555")
data <- tibble(street, citystate)

for(i in 1:length(data$street)){
  data$street[i] <- gsub(data$citystate[i], '', data$street[i])
}
```